# ООП в JavaScript наследование

Tags: javascript, ооп

Почему не работает второй вариант?
И можно ли что бы родительские свойства были в прототипе?
 `a.call(this)` по этой причине не подходит.

```js
function A() {
  this.one = 1;
}

function B() {
  this.two = 2;
}
B.prototype = new A();
x = new B();
console.log(x);

function a() {
  this.one = 1;
}

function b() {
  this.constructor.prototype = new a();
  this.two = 2;
}
z = new b();
console.log(z);
console.log(new b());
```

Comment: что значит не работает? Какой результат ожидался и какой получился?

Comment: @Grundy Маленький гномик высунулся из компьютера и сказал: "Не работает!".

Comment: Посмотрите на строчку, которую я добавил в самом конце. Наводит на определенные мысли, не правда ли? Те же мысли, что и в ответе.

Comment: @Igor Сейчас пересмотрел и возник вопрос почему при втором вызове срабатывает?Первый раз при создании объекта он создается со 'стандартным прототипом' и инициализирует новый прототип который заменяется в последующих объектах. Верны ли мои рассуждения?

Comment: @JarryRoxwell да, верны

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Не работает", так как внутри конструктора объект уже создан и его прототип назначен.

Так как меняется целиком объект прототипа, это никак не отразится на уже созданных объектах.

Вместо этого можно перенести все свойства из объекта `new a()` в сам прототип, например так:

```js
function a() {
  this.one = 1;
}

function b() {
  Object.assign(this.constructor.prototype, new a());
  this.two = 2;
}
z = new b();
console.log(z);
```

---

Однако обновлять прототип для всех созданных объектов, при каждом создании объектов может быть не очень хорошей идеей.

Comment: Глупый наверное вопрос, но почему это плохая идея?

Comment: @JarryRoxwell, потому что прототипом пользуются все объекты сразу, и обычно нет смысла менять _все свойства_ при создании _каждого объекта_, причем меняются на те же самые. Да и смысла нет выполнять одно и то же много раз, если достаточно выполнить один раз, установив прототип как в первом варианте - до создания объекта.